# How to avoid offset between pcolor()/imshow() and contour() overlays?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to show a pseudocolor image (such as produced by pcolor, pcolormesh or imshow) overlayed with contourlines. It appears that those three plot functions can be one data point off. Here's an example:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot,cm

f = pyplot.figure(figsize=(3,2))
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

data = numpy.ones((10,10))
data[5,5] = 2.0
data[0,:] = data[-1,:] = 0
data[:,0] = data[:,-1] = 0

X=numpy.linspace(-3,3,10)
Y=numpy.linspace(-2,2,10)

ax.imshow(data,interpolation='nearest',extent=(-3,3,-2,2),aspect='auto')
ax.contour(X,Y,data,cmap=cm.Greys)
f.subplots_adjust(bottom=.2)

pyplot.show()
```

This produces (with the TkAgg backend GUI):

[image: imshow() example]

Substituting the imshow() method with

```
ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,data)
```

yields:

[image: pcolormesh() example]

In both cases, the contour lines don't match the underlying image.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot,cm

f = pyplot.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

data = numpy.ones((10,10))
data[5,5] = 2.0
data[0,:] = data[-1,:] = 0
data[:,0] = data[:,-1] = 0

ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
ax.contour(data,levels=[0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.5],cmap=cm.Greys)
ax.invert_yaxis()
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. However, this does only work for very special cases. I have updated my question with a different example, where both imshow() and pcolor() produce strange results.